# classes like dictionaries, infinite lists

Tags: python, function, dictionary, generator

I have a bunch of classes that each have one argument to `__init__` and then return some data, e.g.,

```
class Animal(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        if name == 'lion':
            self.sound = 'roar'
        elif name == 'human':
            self.sound = 'burp'
        else:
            raise ValueError('Unknown animal')

class Passenger(object):
    def __init__(self, index):
        self.sound = 'I\'m passenger number %d.' % index
```

Some of these classes are essentially lists or dictionaries (like `Animal`), some are "open-end" (like `Prime`). After instantiating any of the classes, they are used elsewhere, so it's nice that you can instantiate them in the same way (`Something(arg)`).

What's *not* nice though is the fact that, as a user, I don't know which are valid keys without looking at the code. Something like

```
animals = {
    'lion': {'sound': 'roar'},
    'human': {'sound': 'burp'},
    }
```

would solve that problem, but `Passenger` doesn't fit in here.

Is there a design pattern that fits both cases?

Comment: You could make that dictionary a class variable.  The real object-oriented approach is to have `Lion` and `Human` be classes that extend `Animal`

Answer (score 0):

```
class Animal(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def some_thing_all_animals_do(self):
        print('do stuff')

class Passenger(Animal):
    def stuff_only_passengers_do(self):
        print('more stuff')

class Lion(Animal):
    def stuff_only_lions_do(self):
        print('lion stuff')
```

This way, both passengers and lions will "know" the method `some_thing_all_animals_do` and will take a name on initialization.  You can modify this to do whatever you need for whatever animals you need, and it makes it much easier and intuitive than using conditionals inside of the same class.